# Performance penalty using intermediate model (Map) for Jackson/GSON serialising

Tags: json, performance, serialization, jackson, gson

I have a project where I need to support serialising model classes to JSON using both Jackson and GSON (switchable).

Besides simply converting these model classes to JSON I also need to manipulate the by adding/removed certain keys (as per user input).

I was thinking of converting my model classes (and the logic to remove/add data) to simple `java.util.Map`s and convert these to JSON. Which works.

To convert these model classes to the `java.util.Map`s for Jackson I'm doing:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = 
    mapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>() {})
```

and for GSON:

```
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(object);
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = 
    gson.fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

After manipulating the data in the map, I do the following to actually serialize the map to JSON string:

```
// Jackson
mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
// GSON
gson.toJson(jsonMap);
```

1. Is there a performance hit to convert a model `Object` to a `Map` instead of a Jackson `JsonNode` (`mapper.convertValue(object, ..)` vs. `mapper.valueToTree(object)`)?
2. Would it be possible to directly convert a model `Object` to a `Map` using GSON? Now I'm first creating a `JsonElement` and then converting it to a `Map`.

Comment: Regarding the first question… did you already make a performance analysis e.g. with such lightweight tools like [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson's `ObjectNode` uses `LinkedHashMap` internally (and `ArrayNode` uses `ArrayList`), so there should not be much difference between these approaches. `JsonNode` model can optimize some things slightly better than "raw" `List`s and `Map`s; but on the other hand there is thin wrapper that adds some memory usage... so in the end things probably even out.